# Trying to get tab in normal mode(VSCode using the vscode-neovim extension) to move to new cell in a markdown table

Tags: vim, visual-studio-code, markdown, neovim

I'm seeking assistance with the VSCode-Neovim extension to enhance navigation in markdown tables.

The current markdown extension that I am using is takumisoft68/vscode-markdown-table, which has this setting in the settings.json file:

```
{
"key": "tab",

"command": "markdowntable.nextCell",

"when": "editorTextFocus && markdowntable.contextkey.selection.InMarkdownTable && !editorReadonly && !editorTabMovesFocus && !inSnippetMode && !suggestWidgetMultipleSuggestions && !suggestWidgetVisible"
},
```

The above allows me to jump to the next cell while in insert mode in a markdown table and automatically formats the table. I would like to replicate this functionality. IntelliJ's markdown extension also has this functionality, but the jump and format occur in normal mode.

**Desired Behaviour in Normal Mode**

I want to replicate this behaviour in normal mode. At the moment, when I press Tab in normal mode, nothing happens. I want to jump to the next cell in the table and have the table automatically formatted.

Any insights or suggestions would be highly appreciated.

I have tried editing Tab in my .vim, but it has not worked.

`nnoremap tab i<Tab>`

I have attached a picture of the current keybindings related to Tab in my keyboard shortcut.

[image: Picture of tab specific settings.json]